# Postgres preventing update on "events" table but insert "warning" event

Tags: postgresql, permissions, trigger, update, functions

I'm facing a bit of a problem on some restrictions I'm trying to implement on my postgresql database.

My dilemma is as follows: I have an event table that logs basically everything that happens on my app, it can't be updated or deleted directly from the app (only inserts work), but I also need to prevent anyone from updating or deleting using a manual query (when conecting from dbeaver for example), I know I can do this by revoking permissions to the table, problem is, at the same time, I need to insert into that table an event that someone tried to manually update it, and when I revoke restrictions its becoming impossible.

I was creating a trigger as follows, and the restriction works but its not inserting anything into my table, could anyone help me out?

```
--Create event on event table update attempt
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION protect_events_on_update() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
 username VARCHAR;
BEGIN
  -- Get special variable values
  SELECT current_user INTO username;
  INSERT INTO events (uuid,description) VALUES (someUUID, username || 'tried to modify the table');         
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER protect_events_on_update_trigg BEFORE UPDATE ON events FOR EACH row EXECUTE PROCEDURE protect_events_on_update();

REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE events FROM user;
GRANT INSERT ON TABLE events TO user;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE events TO user;
```

Comment: If you revoke the update privilege, the update statement won't be allowed, so there would be nothing to invoke the trigger either.

Answer (score 0):

[It is possible](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) to write

```
RETURN NULL;
```

instead of `RETURN NEW` to skip this operation.

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger
> manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e.,
> subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does
> not occur for this row)

---

Typically, in such cases, the rights to modify the table are revoked. Erroneous attempts to modify data are tracked through the database log.